# looping in 3d array access vba not returning all results

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-access

I have a project with 4 scheduled payments associated with 4 "contract" dates, stored in tblPaySch However, sometimes we receive the payments (stored in tblTrans), in different amounts on different dates (the "Actual") date

I am attempting an array that defines the 4 dates (identified by ID 1 - 4) and the expected amount, then compares it against the tblTrans to to see if the expected payment has been exceeded, and if so, mark that transaction date as the "Actual" date.

There's either something wrong with my array or something wrong with my loop, as I can get the results for ID1, (i.e, the associate expected pay and the transaction date that met it), but can't get the other 3 IDs.

I'm calling it in a query with GetDate(prjID) to pass the prjId to the function.

Here is my code:

```
'This function is a multidimensional array that can hold multiple values
Public Function GetDate(intID As Long) As Variant

    Dim intTot As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim i2 As Integer

    'Define recordset to get expected payment data
    Dim rsPrj As DAO.Recordset 
    Set rsPrj = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblPaySch WHERE PrjID =" & intID, dbOpenSnapshot)

    'Define recordset to get transaction data
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * from tblTrans where PrjID=" & intID, dbOpenSnapshot)


    'Store milestone payments in RA
    Dim RA(0 To 4, 0 To 4, 0 To 4) As Variant
    RA(0, 0, 0) = rsPrj!MSCdbID 'payment Id, 4 of which are associated with each PrjID
    RA(0, 1, 0) = rsPrj!PayIncGST 'expected payment amount, of 4 different totals
    RA(0, 0, 1) = rs!RefDate 'Actual date from tblTrans
    intTot = 0

    Do While rs.EOF
        intTot = intTot + rs!Amt 'refers to the amount of the transaction
        '-----Check for milestone exceeded
        For i = 0 To 4
            For i2 = 0 To 4
                If IsNull(RA(i, i2, 1) And RA(i, i2, 0) <= intTot) Then
                        RA(i, i2, 1) = rs!RefDate
                 End If
            Next i2
        Next i

    Loop

    GetDate = RA(0, 0, 1)

    Debug.Print RA(1, 0, 0)
    Debug.Print RA(0, 1, 0)
    Debug.Print RA(0, 0, 1)

End Function
```

Thank you in advance, and please excuse any obvious noobie mistakes, this is my first ever array function.

Comment: should you be using `IsEmpty()` instead of `IsNull()` function?, and I think you mean  `If IsEmpty(RA(i, i2, 1)) And RA(i, i2, 0) <= intTot Then`  The () is in wrong location, I think the condition will never be matched.   You should try to debug by stepping into each line.

Comment: Do you mean: Do While rs.EOF?

On reading this, I must admit that my first thought is that it's such a complicated approach that I'd give in and take an easier one.  Multi-dimensional arrays are rarely the answer to anything in VBA.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the changes you suggested, but I'm still getting the same result - I have 90 records and Debug.print (1,0,0) is returning 1 for all 90, instead of 1,2,3,4 for each prjid. I'm retrying as a 1 dimensional function and going to try building up from there.

Comment: @Andy, I agree, it is very complicated and I'm just about at the point of giving up myself. I've been at it for nearly 2 days now and still can't work it out. If you have any ideas of an easier way to do this, I'd really appreciate a pointer.

Comment: Could you provide a sample layout of what your data would look like?

Comment: @Zaider tblPaySch is:

Comment: @Zaider tblPaySch is:
PrjID:PayID:ExpectedAmt:DatePaid(trying to find from tblTrans)
1       1     $100
1       2     $150
1       3     $100
1       4     $200

tblTrans is:
PrjID:AmtPaid:PayDate
1     $250     12/03/12
2     $765     05/05/12
3     $150     06/05/12
1     $200     07/06/12
1     $100     08/07/12

Comment: well, that didn't work either

Comment: The fact that this is proving so darned difficult tells me that I must be approaching this whole problem in the wrong way.

Comment: I second that!  The problem is that I can't quite see what you're trying to do.  Have you used DSUM and DCOUNT?  I suspect they might help get an easier answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I see what you are trying to do.  Lets see if we can simplify this a bit.

First you have your table structures (DatePaid is the value you want to update?):

**tblPaySch is:**

```
PrjID    PayID    ExpectedAmt    DatePaid(trying to find from tblTrans) 
1          1         $100 
1          2         $150 
1          3         $100 
1          4         $200
```

**tblTrans is:**  (assuming date format is DD/MM/YYYY and always sorted chronologically)

```
PrjID AmtPaid   PayDate 
1       $250    12/03/12
2       $765    05/05/12
3       $150    06/05/12
1       $200    07/06/12
1       $100    08/07/12
```

I assumed that it could take multiple transactions to meet an expected payment amount but that payments could also be greater than expected.  I used the column names you gave in your sample data for field names.

I have hopefully added enough comments to the code that it will be useful for you.

```
Private Function GetDate(intID As Long) As Variant
    Dim intTot As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim i2 As Integer
    Dim loopCounter As Integer

    'Define recordset to get expected payment data
    Dim rsPrj As DAO.Recordset
    Set rsPrj = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblPaySch WHERE PrjID =" & intID)

    'Define recordset to get transaction data
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * from tblTrans where PrjID=" & intID, dbOpenSnapshot)

    ' get rs.recordcount and go back to the beginning
    rs.MoveLast
    rs.MoveFirst

    ' Only need to store the records returned and the 2 fields Payment amount and payment date
    Dim RA() As Variant
    ReDim RA(0 To rs.RecordCount - 1, 0 To 1)

    ' Populate the array with the transaction records
    i = 0
    Do Until rs.EOF
        RA(i, 0) = rs!AmtPaid
        RA(i, 1) = rs!PayDate
        If rs.RecordCount <> 0 Then
            rs.MoveNext
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Loop

    intTot = 0
    loopCounter = 0 ' This will ensure we don't check transactions more than once

    ' First we're going to loop through the payment schedule and see at which payment from table transaction
    ' the scheduled payment is met
    Do Until rsPrj.EOF
        ' First we check if the last payment was enough to make this scheduled payment to and if so mark it paid
        ' otherwise check for the next transaction that gives us enough
        If intTot < rsPrj!ExpectedAmt Then
            For i = loopCounter To UBound(RA)
                intTot = intTot + RA(i, 0)
                If intTot >= rsPrj!ExpectedAmt Then ' if the current payment is = or greater than expected set the date
                    rsPrj.edit
                    rsPrj!DatePaid = RA(i, 1)
                    rsPrj.Update
                    intTot = intTot - rsPrj!ExpectedAmt  ' update our remainder
                    loopCounter = loopCounter + 1 ' increase this so we don't double check a transaction
                    Exit For ' exit loop and move to the next expected payment
                End If
            Next i
        Else
            rsPrj.edit
            rsPrj!DatePaid = RA(i, 1)
            rsPrj.Update
            intTot = intTot - rsPrj!ExpectedAmt
        End If
        If rsPrj.RecordCount <> 0 Then
            rsPrj.MoveNext
        End If
    Loop
End Function
```

Comment: thank you so much, it basically worked straight out of the box. I was really going about it all ass-before-face. Not only that, but this example has clarified several concepts I've been reading about but not really getting, like dynamic arrays, the loop process and editing records from VBA. I notice you changed the first rs from opensnapshot, did a little digging and found out that you can't modify snapshot rs. That would have tripped me up for ages. Profoundly grateful!